# HyperlinkedIdentityField + @detail_route

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In Django Rest Framework, how can I point my `HyperlinkedIdentityfield` at a `@detail_route` defined in a `ViewSet`?

For example, maybe I have `api/groups/members/` and members is defined as a `@detail_route` on the `GroupsViewSet` which returns currently active members. How would I expose `members: "api/groups/members/"` in my response using `HyperlinkedIdentityField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of unclear, but I'm guessing you wonder about what the URL pattern name is for the detail_route? It will be <basename>-<methodname>, so if the basename of GroupsViewSet is "group" and the detail_route method is "members" you would add something like this to the serializer where you want the reference:

```
field_name = HyperlinkedIdentityfield(view_name="group-members")
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. How'd you find this? Didn't see anything mentioning this in the docs.

Comment: It's not clear, no. You can tell from looking at the code in the [Example](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#example).